# Is there a way to add a link to the current repo in Github README.md?

Tags: git, github, readme

Most of my repos' README.md files include instructions on how to clone/build/run/test the code:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/TravelingTechGuy/app-store-validator.git
$ cd app-store-validator
$ npm i
$ npm run build    #lint and build
$ npm run test     #run unit tests
```

The problem is the link is repo-specific, i.e. if the repo has been forked/transferred, the README would still contain a link to my original repo. I ran into at least one case of someone forking a repo, and then copy/pasting the installation instructions, and not understanding why changes are not present.

My question: is there any way to put a link to the **current** repo in the README file? Such that when cloned, will point to the cloned repo?

Comment: I don't think there is. Anyway, the URl stands on the right-hand pane anyway and this change is trivial for a forked repo to make.

Comment: I know it's there, but `$ git clone <paste link copied from right pane here>` is a bit unwieldy :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The markdown file is static. There is no way to do that.

Instruct your users to copy the URL from the widget on the right column:

[image]

Comment: Instructing my users has never been a problem - I just want to see if I can get the URI in automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. It would make a nice feature request though. The only supported custom link type is links to wiki pages like `[[Link Text|WikiLink]]`.

Comment: I thought, since there's a way to have relative links in the MD (https://help.github.com/articles/relative-links-in-readmes/), I should be able to have a `.` type of link

Comment: Giving up - will let users figure on their own :)